# TypeScript Map.has expect literal types

Tags: typescript, dictionary

`Map.has` only expects key that is defined when it was constructed, so checking is string is a key of map is impossible without some weird unneeded code. Code:

```
const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]] as const);
const inMap = (str: string) => map.has(str)

[eval].ts:2:40 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.

2 const inMap = (str: string) => map.has(str)
                                         ~~~
```

How to overcome that and preserve strict types?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but what if you did
new Map<string, number> instead? You would still have strict types and typescript would know that the key should be a string and therefore would have no issues with the code.

Comment: @Sentinel I can, but my goal is to have values of Map to be certain and not just `string`

Comment: They would be typed. In the case of Map<string, number> the value would have to be a number. Instead of number you could obviously also define your own type and use that instead. Sorry if I just misunderstand your question btw.